# Python global dict across different file script

Tags: python, file, dictionary, global

Hello. I am trying to use a global `dict` created in `main.py`, which is called in `functions.py`.
In my **main.py** I have:

```
import sys,os,...
import functions.py #import my second file

matrix = {}
matrix_do_something
search_the_matrix(value) #which is defined in functions.py

#FILE: functions.py
def search_the_matrix(value):
    global matrix
    if value in matrix:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

**and I get this error:**

```
NameError: global name 'matrix' is not defined
```

I have read a solution on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files-in-python), which says to put everything in a global file and then call from every file global.matrix[value] but I don't want this. I want just call it matrix and think of it as my global matrix. Is this possible?
Thank you in advance

Comment: are you importing `matrix` from `main.py` (in `functions.py`)?

Comment: Also, you don't `import functions.py`, you `import functions`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In functions.py you would have to import it

```
from main import matrix
```

Though I would want to come up with a better name for my module than main.

If you want an object to be available in a module / file you need to either create it there or import it from somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you! i feel so dumb now. I though i could import only functions and files with that import command.

Comment: Every language has it's own concept of the global namespace, so don't worry. Python has a per module namespace. And each function inside a module is inside it's own closure. You generally don't need to use the `global` keyword