# PyDev displays undefined variable from import for 1 out of 2 vars

Tags: python, pydev

### Issue

I have the following structure:

```
home.py
logic/brains/databeam.py
```

Inside `databeam.py` I have:

```
engine  = create_engine(databaseSettings(), pool_size = 20, max_overflow = 0)
Session = sessionmaker(bind = engine)
session = Session()

boom = 'boom'
```

And in `home.py`:

```
from logic.brains.databeam import session, boom

print session
print session.query()
print boom
```

Everything works as intended, but PyDev on eclipse shows me this:

[image: red source]

[image: error message]

### This works when...

Instead of using `from logic.brains.databeam import session as session, boom as boom`, I do this:

```
import logic.brains.databeam
session = logic.brains.databeam.session
boom    = logic.brains.databeam.boom
```

But this seems untidy, is there a better way to show PyDev that the import works?

Comment: Why use `samename as samename` at all? `from logic.brains.databeam import session, boom` is enough.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it produces the same outcome as `as`. So in this case I used it just to try and find a fix.

Comment: You cannot write a 100% working parser for a dynamic language so such problems are expected (and in my experience PyDev had more such problems than e.g. PyCharm).

Comment: @wRAR well that sounds about right, though I do remember a stackoverflow question for the best Python IDE, aside from vim, PyDev had the most votes, so that was my first choice.

Comment: @MorganWilde then either it was old or it was only about freeware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that I found to be reasonable is to suppress this type of error in `PyDev` altogether. I know this is not perfect, but far and away the best one I've come across.

How to change this setting:

[image: pydev settings change]

Comment: for me this has no effect

Comment: Hi Morgan, do you think you can create a sample project with the error (on github) and report an issue to the PyDev tracker pointing to it? https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev -- I'm currently focusing a lot on the PyDev type inference, and the reason you're having this issue is probably because it wasn't able to infer the variable properly and gave you a False positive there.

Answer (score 2):

Really simple script producing the same error in Eclipse 2019-09 with PyDev 8.1.0.202012051215:

```
import re
flag = re.ASCII
```

It seems PyDev isn't inferring things exported using globals().update(). The following is equivalent and works (in this case):

```
import re
flag = re.RegexFlag.ASCII
```

Answer (score 1):

@Lars, I can not comment on previous post, so i will put my comment here.
If you have an error "Undefined variable from import" like @Morgan Wilde had with query, you should put Warning on that option under tab Undefined not Imports.

Answer (score 1):

As a way to circumvent the issue, I used:

[image]

then a bunch of

[image]

and

[image]

will appear. To hide them:

[image]