# Python Global Variable Not Working (3 modules)

Tags: python, mysql, variables, tkinter, global

I am trying to create a program that displays a user's username in a tkinter label after he has logged in. I am trying to follow the instructions for creating global variables found on [this webpage](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules). Here is my (simplified) setup for the code so far:

config.py (where I keep my global variables):

```
nameInput = "Name" # default value of nameInput
print nameInput # prints default value of nameInput just to see if it will change
```

mod.py:

```
import config
import MySQLdb
import Tkinter as tk

#LOGIN FUNCTION 
#Username list
cursor.execute("SELECT Username FROM Student")
username_list = cursor.fetchall()
usernameList = [l[0] for l in username_list]

#Password list
cursor.execute("SELECT Password FROM Student")
password_list = cursor.fetchall()
passwordList = [l[0] for l in password_list]

login_dictionary = dict(zip(usernameList, passwordList))

def loginFunction(c,ue,pwe,mf,sp):
    #nameInput = user input from usernameEntry, which is in main.py
    config.nameInput = ue.get()
    print config.nameInput #prints nameInput again to see if it has changed to user-inputted entry, which it does
    #pwInput is user input from pwEntry
    pwInput = pwe.get()

    #If the username is correct but the password is not...
    if config.nameInput in login_dictionary:
        if pwInput != login_dictionary[config.nameInput]:
        badLoginLabel = tk.Label(mf, text="Invalid Login",
                                 bg="white", fg="red")
        badLoginLabel.grid(row=3, column=1)
        badLoginLabel.after(3000, badLoginLabel.destroy)
    # But if the user name and password are correct... 
    else:
        c.show_frame(sp)
    #If the username AND password are incorrect...      
    else:
        badLoginLabel = tk.Label(mf, text="Invalid Login",
                                 bg="white", fg="red")
        badLoginLabel.grid(row=3, column=1)
        badLoginLabel.after(3000, badLoginLabel.destroy)
```

main.py:

```
import config
import mod
import Tkinter as tk

class UserProfile(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
               tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

    header = Header(self, controller)
    header.grid(row=0,column=0)

    #creates frame for main content
    mainFrame = tk.Frame(self, width=windowWidth, height=500, bg="white")
    mainFrame.grid(row=3,column=0)

    #User Profile Name
    profileName = tk.Label(mainFrame, text=config.nameInput,
                          bg="white", font=("TkDefaultFont", 14),
                           anchor=tk.W)
    profileName.grid(row=0,column=0, padx=5, pady=2, sticky=tk.W)

    mainFrame.grid_propagate(False)
```

*Here is the "login page" in main.py that calls loginFunction:

```
class LoginPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        #creates frame for main content
        mainFrame = tk.Frame(self, width=windowWidth, height=500, bg="white")
        mainFrame.grid(row=3,column=0)
        instructions = tk.Label(mainFrame, text="Login",
                             bg="white", anchor=tk.W)
        instructions.grid(row=0,column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.W)

        #Username field
        usernameLabel = tk.Label(mainFrame, text="Username:",
                                 bg="white")
        usernameLabel.grid(row=1,column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
        usernameEntry = tk.Entry(mainFrame, width="20")
        usernameEntry.grid(row=1,column=1)

        #Password field
        pwLabel = tk.Label(mainFrame, text="Password:",
                                 bg="white")
        pwLabel.grid(row=2,column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
        pwEntry = tk.Entry(mainFrame, width="20", show="*")
        pwEntry.grid(row=2,column=1)

        #login button
        loginButton = tk.Button(mainFrame, text="Login",
                                command=lambda: mod.loginFunction(controller,usernameEntry,
                                                              pwEntry, mainFrame,
                                                              StartPage))
        loginButton.grid(row=3,column=0)

        mainFrame.grid_propagate(False)
```

My problem is this: the profileName label in main.py will not display the user's username. It will only display the default value, which is "Name"
The strange thing is that right after I log in, "print config.nameInput" in mod.py DOES print the username's name. But for some reason it just doesn't display in the label.
If you need more information let me know. I really need to solve this problem in order to proceed on my project.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13034908/1189040) ?

Comment: Yes, I have seen that. Unfortunately, I am unsure how to call loginFunction in my UserProfile class so that it can recognize that nameInput has changed. I am a bit new at this, sorry.

Comment: You could use `textvariable` (with a  StringVar) for your `usernameLabel`.  so, If the variable is changed, the label text is updated.

Comment: I tried that. I am not sure if I am doing it right but basically, I replaced text=config.nameInput in the usernameLabel to textvariable = config.nameInput

And before that, I typed "config.nameInput = tk.StringVar()"

All it does is display PY_VAR0 instead of the default value "Name"

Comment: You have to use `set()` and `get()` with that.like, `config.nameInput.set('Name')`

Comment: Your advice worked, thanks!!!

Comment: @Himal: you should write an answer...

Comment: @EricLevieil feel free to post an answer.