# Best way to share global variables between files in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables, global

I was wondering what the best way is to use global variables in a multi-script python project.
I've seen this question: [Using global variables between files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files-in-python) - and while the accepted answer works, the solution seems clunky.

See the below set of scripts. Only main.py is ever called directly; the rest are imported.

First, I've declared my global variables in a separate file:

```
#global_vars.py
my_string = "hello world"
```

The `main.py` prints the value of the string using a custom function, changes the value of the global variable, and then prints the new value

```
#main.py
import global_vars
import do_things_module

#Print the instantiated value of the global string
do_things_module.my_function()

#Change the global variable globally
global_vars.my_string = "goodbye"

#Print the new value of the global string
do_things_module.my_function()
```

`do_things_module.py` contains our custom print function, and gets the string straight from the global

```
#do_things_module.py
import global_vars

def my_function():
    print(global_vars.my_string)
```

Having to keep referencing `global_vars.my_string` rather than just `my_string` to ensure I'm always reading/writing to the global scoped variable seems long-winded and not very 'pythonic'. Is there a better/neater way?

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to use `my_string` instead of `global_vars.my_string`, you could import the module like this:

```
from global_vars import *
```

You should be able to use `my_string` directly.

Comment: Terrible practice to do this randomly, though

Answer (score 1):

I would go with

```
import global_vars as g
```

Then you can refer to `my_string` from `global_vars` module as `g.my_string` in your code.

It doesn't use a lot of space, but it is still clear, that `my_string` came from `global_vars` and namespace isn't polluted

If you need only a few `global_vars` variables in your current module you can import only them

```
from global_vars import my_string, my_int
```

and reference to them as `my_string` and `my_int`

Answer (score 1):

Best of all ("explicit is better than implicit") use

```
from module import name [as name] ...
```

but don't then expect to be able to modify the values seen by other modules (though you *can* mutate mutable objects, should you choose).