# Py.test: Run initialization method before pytest_generate_tests

Tags: python, pytest

I'm making a test suite using `py.test` that starts by generating randomly simulated files and the filenames are stored in an initialization object. The tests are then generated by `pytest_generate_tests`; `file0.txt`, `file1.txt`, etc.
Tests are generated from a YAML file which includes in input string like `cat %s` and a substitution string like `file*.txt`, which generates 1 test per file it matches in `pytest_generate_tests`. Thus, I need the files to exist before `pytest_generate_tests` is called, else files won't be matched.

Before I had encountered the issue, I had an initialization fixture in `conftest.py`:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def initializer(request):
    # ...do some stuff with the request
    return InitializeTests(...)

class InitializeTests():
    def __init__(self, n):
        # ...generate n files
```

which I could then use in the file `tests_0.py`:

```
test_a(initializer, input_string):
    # ...
```

and `test_a`'s are generated by:

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    input_strings = manipulate_the_yaml_file() # This requires the files to exist.
    if "input_string" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        metafunc.parametrize("input_string", input_strings)
```

I then tried using a global variable to get the initializer and share it across the files as explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13034908/3895928). I then put the initialization at the top of `pytest_generate_tests` and calling conftest.initializer from within `test_a`, but then the initialization step gets run for every test method I add, `test_b` etc.

So the question is, how can I run a method before `pytest_generate_tests` and keep the instance of the initialization class across all tests in the session?

Comment: Just promoting your question to know about the correct technique to make it happen..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just writing the problem gave me an obvious solution given the second method using globals:

```
if "initializer" not in globals():
    initialize()
```

where `initialize` creates the global variable `initializer` and thus only creates it once. However, I don't really like working with globals as I thought fixtures or some other `py.test` technique could help me, and would gladly hear a better answer.