# Global variable from multiple file in python

Tags: python, global

I have searched a lot in different forums including [Using global variables between files in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files-in-python) and couldn't find any proper answer for my question though there are some topics discussing about global variable and multiple files. I created three dummy codes to explain my question.

**globalss.py**

```
test_value = [0]
```

**test.py**

```
from globalss import *
def datagen():
  global test_value
  test_value = [100]
  print('test_value from datagen', test_value)
datagen()
def valchange(x):
  global test_value
  test_value = [x]
  print('test value in val change', test_value)
valchange(1000)
```

**testing.py**

```
from test import *
from globalss import *
print('test_value from testing', test_value)
valchange(22222)
print('test_value from testing', test_value)
```

testing.py is the file i ran as **main**.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7oaf.png)

```
test_value from datagen [100]
test value in val change [1000]
test_value from testing [0]
test value in val change [22222]
test_value from testing [0]
```

Regardless of operations applied on test_value, testing.py has 0 as its value. 
So basically from this test codes what i understood is, a module will get the value for a global variable when it is imported. After that whatever happens to that variable from other files, it would not get reflected in that particular module.

All the answers i found from another pages are talking about initializing the variable in a common file and import that file in different modules. As i have shown in the example, that will import the value. but once imported, changes made after that in other files would populate in current file.

My question is, is there a way to share global variables across different file where the values changes will be reflected in all the files.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the output as text.

Comment: I couldn't understand how this question become the duplicate of what jonrsharpe pointed. I have tried the solutions given in that page as well. That solutions are right. But not an answer for my question. @jonrsharpe

Comment: Then please edit the question to clarify how it's different.

Comment: @jonrsharpe. yes i did. :)

Comment: Why don't you *mutate* the shared variable, e.g. `test_value[0] = 100`, rather than *replacing* it with `test_value = [100]`?

Comment: Wow!! i didnt see that coming :). But what if it is a non mutable object like string.

Comment: You can't do this with immutable objects, whether global or not. Just put it in a (mutable) list, like you've done with the (also immutable) integer.

Comment: No, that wouldn't make any sense, *it's immutable*.

Comment: OK Great!! Thats a nice workaround. Thanks a lot man. Could you please post that as the answer? @jonrsharpe

Comment: ...but that's exactly what the answers in the question you claim isn't a duplicate suggest, sharing a mutable object like a list that can be modified throughout your program.