# Update variable from imported module with Python when using Threading

Tags: python, global-variables, python-multithreading

In a project, I would like to separate the visualization and calculation in two different modules. The goal is to transfer the variables of the calculation-module to a main-script, in order to visualize it with the visualization-script.

Following this post
[Using global variables between files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files),
I am able to use a config-script in order to transfer a variable between to scripts now. But unfortunately, this is not working when using threading. The Output of the main.py is always "get: 1".

Does anyone have an idea?

main.py:

```python
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

import viz

import change
add_Thread = Thread(target=change.add)
add_Thread.start()
```

viz.py:

```python
import config

from time import sleep

while True:
    config.init()
    print("get:", config.x)
    sleep(1)
```

config.py:

```python
x = 1

def init():
    global x
```

change.py:

```python
import config

def add():
    while True:
        config.x += 1
        config.init()
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, fount the answer by myself. Problem was in the "main.py". One has to put the "import viz" after starting the thread:

```python
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

import change
add_Thread = Thread(target=change.add)
add_Thread.start()

import viz
```