# Global modules across the files in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables

Any one help me how to declare global variables across the python files

In Below python file  i have declared the global variable var1:

```
 File locations for settings.py:
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/project/settings.py
```

settings.py

```
global var1
var1 = ""
```

python file2.py:

```
 Location:
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/file2.py
```

file2.py

```
from dev import fullchip
from project import settings
a = 10
b = 20
fullchip.count (a, b)
print var1
```

script fullchip.py

```
 location
 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dev/fullchip.py
```

script fullchip.py

```
 from projects import settings
 def count(a, b):
     global var
     var1 = a + b
```

I am running file2.py

I am expecting var1 to print "30" but i am getting var1 not defined. Basically I want to use var1 as global variables  across all the files

Comment: Have you tried calling `project.var1`?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files

Comment: @moritzg, no var1 only

Comment: @asteroid4u Also your code in fullchip.py reads `global var` shouldn't it be `global var1`?

Comment: @bigbounty, I gone through your link before posting this question but still i am having issue

Comment: You should use `settings.var1` to access it in file2.py

Comment: @yeniv, Tried print settings.var1 in file2.py but now nothing is printing but error var1 not coming. might be it is pulling from settings.py directly since settings.py value is empty

Comment: Use it in similar manner in fullchip.py also where the `var1` value has to be updated.

Comment: when i used same in fullchip. I am getting variable not defined error

Comment: @yeniv, Thanks it works sorry in above comment mentioned wrong comment..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: I am expecting var1 to print "20" but i am getting var1 not define

1. Misspelled `project` and `projects`

   File locations for settings.py:
   `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/project/settings.py`

   but uses

   `from projects import settings`
2. This works for me, no `global` required:

   ```
   from dev import fullchip
   from project import settings

   a = 10
   b = 20
   fullchip.count (a, b)
   print(settings.var1)
   ```

> **Output**

```
30
```