# variable same values sharing in 2 python script files

Tags: python, function, variables, import

Hello everyone,
              i have one python script file that creates a moving object therefore its coordinates(of created object that can be sphere , box etc) are changing and i want to use the these changing variable in another file so that both files get the same value of that variable at a specific time. Please tell me that How can i do it. All helps are appreciated. Thanks. Given Below is the code that generates the variable for both files.

```
zp = 0
def givalue();
        global zp
        if zp > 0.4:
            zp = 0.1
            return zp
        else:
            zp = zp + 0.1
            return zp
while 1:
    z = givalue()
    print 'value of zp is ', z
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using global variables between files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files)

Answer (score 0):

Sharing values through global variables in files is generally not considered as a correct design. It is much more powerful and flexible to create a base class storing the shared data and a arbitrary number of derived classes that need access to this shared data. Here is a skeleton for that pattern:

```
class Shared(object):
  shared = [0, 0] # put all shared values in a list or a dictionary

class C1(Shared):
  def __init__(self):
    print('C1: shared =', self.shared)
  def update(self, index):
    self.shared[index] += 1
    print('C1: shared =', self.shared)

class C2(Shared):
  def __init__(self):
    print('C2: shared =', self.shared)
  def update(self, index):
    self.shared[index] += 1
    print('C2: shared =', self.shared)

c1 = C1()
c1.update(0)
c2 = C2()
c2.update(0)
c2.update(1)
c1.update(1)
```

Result:

```
C1: shared = [0, 0]
C1: shared = [1, 0]
C2: shared = [1, 0]
C2: shared = [2, 0]
C2: shared = [2, 1]
C1: shared = [2, 2]
```

Of course all three classes may be in three different source files, just `import` before using them

If you **REALLY** insist on not using the OO paradigm, the following code may fulfil your wishes:

```
# --------------
# shared.py
# --------------
shared = [0,0] # put all shared values in a list or a dictionary

# --------------
# C1.py
# --------------
from shared import *
print('C1: shared =', shared)
shared[0] += 1
print('C1: shared =', shared)

# --------------
# C2.py
# --------------
from shared import *
print('C2: shared =', shared)
shared[0] += 1
print('C2: shared =', shared)
```

The magic works from the fact that an imported file is only executed when it is imported for the first time, so the `shared` variable will not be reset when `shared.py` is imported the second time.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help. my problem was solved as i made simple functions and called them in the other file and used the break statement because both files had infinite while loop.