# Global DataFrame across files in a project

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, global-variables

I'm trying to define a variable accesible to all my files (modules) in a Python Project. To do so, I defined a file `Config.py`, in there I tried both

```
#Config.py  ##1

import pandas as pd
GDF=pd.DataFrame()


#Config.py  ##2

import pandas as pd

def init():
  global GDF
  GDF=pd.DataFrame()
```

The structure of the program is to have a table, and across several modules get some rows.
I tried

```
#Functions.py 
import Config

def RandomFunct():
   Config.GDF.append([a,b,c,d],ignore_index=True)

#Main.py
import Config

some code
print(Config.GDF)
```

What I get is an empty DataFrame. I tried all possible alternatives exposed in this thread [Using global variables between files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files) but to no avail.

Can anybody enlighten me on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not calling init() in main.py. Also you need to store the changes to DF

try

```
# Config.py
import pandas as pd

def init():
    global GDF
    GDF=pd.DataFrame()


#Functions.py 
import Config

def RandomFunct():
   Config.GDF = Config.GDF.append([a,b,c,d],ignore_index=True)

# main.py

import settings
import Functions

Config.init()
Functions.RandomFunct()
print(Config.GDF)
```

Comment: Apparently, what was amiss was that I did `Config.GDF.append()` instead of doing `Config.GDF=Config.GDF.append()`.  It is now solved, thank you very much