# Python 3, Global Variables, Modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, global

how can I move this code to a function in a module?
I have global var 'last_msg' and 'fake'. I was trying use 'global' for 'last_msg' in my function, but it out of scope because function in a module, but 'last_msg' in main scope.

```
main.py

from module import Timeout

last_msg = {'Foo': 0}
name = 'Foo'
fake = False
timeout = 3

fake = Timeout(fake, name, timeout)

>> NameError: name 'last_msg' is not defined
```

<>

```
module.py

def Timeout(fake, name, timeout):
    global last_msg

    if not fake:
        if name not in last_msg:
            last_msg[name] = 0

        if last_msg[name] > 0:
            last_msg[name] -= 1
            fake = True
        else:
            last_msg[name] = timeout
    else:
        if name in last_msg:
            last_msg[name] = 0

    return fake
```

Comment: Your code is not enough for us to say what the issue is. You have no `import` anywhere in your example, or traceback.

Comment: I updated it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files) has some information about how you can access globals and how python treats globals. For that the code will be:

```
module.py
def Timeout(fake, name, timeout):
    import main

    if not fake:
        if name not in main.last_msg:
            main.last_msg[name] = 0

        if main.last_msg[name] > 0:
            main.last_msg[name] -= 1
            fake = True
        else:
            main.last_msg[name] = timeout
    else:
        if name in main.last_msg:
            main.last_msg[name] = 0

    return fake
```

and the `main.py` would look like this:

```
last_msg = {'Foo': 0}
from module import Timeout

# last_msg = {'Foo': 0}
name = 'Foo'
fake = False
timeout = 3

fake = Timeout(fake, name, timeout)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems I've done it.

```
main.py

from module import Timeout

last_msg = {'Foo': 0}
name = 'Foo'
fake = False
timeout = 3

fake, last_msg = Timeout(fake, name, last_msg, timeout)
```

<>

```
module.py

def Timeout(fake, name, last_msg, timeout):
    if not fake:
        if name not in last_msg:
            last_msg[name] = 0

        if last_msg[name] > 0:
            last_msg[name] -= 1
            fake = True
        else:
            last_msg[name] = timeout
    else:
        if name in last_msg:
            last_msg[name] = 0

    return fake, last_msg
```

Comment: Be cool man, really. It's the best thing if you've done what you want.