# Global variable sharing across different modules behave differently

Tags: python

In config.py, I have:

```
config = 0
#config = []
def init_config():
    global config
    config = 1
    #config.append("1")
    print("init", config)
```

In main.py, I have:

```
from config import init_config
from config import config

def main():
    init_config()
    print("main", config)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And both the config.py and the main.py in the same directory. After running `python main.py`, I got:

```
init 1
main 0
```

But if I use the comment lines in the config.py instead, I got:

```
init ['1']
main ['1']
```

So why does the difference happen? (Python 3.5.5)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using global variables between files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Hi, I have restated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once imported from `config.py`, the variable `config` becomes a separate copy of `config.config` that lives in `main.py`'s namespace. You should `import config` as a module and then access the variable `config` as an attribute to the module `config` instead:

```
import config

def main():
    config.init_config()
    print("main", config.config)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you explain why the modified code by using list is OK?

Comment: This is because a list variable actually stores just a reference to the list, so when you import `config` as a list from the `config` module, even though you're making a copy of the `config` variable in the `config` module into `main.py`'s namespace, the copy of the value still has the reference to the same list in memory, so in this case modifying the list in the `config` module can still be accessed through the copy of the `config` variable in `main.py`.