# Shared config variable between multiple processes

Tags: python, dictionary, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, multiple-processes

Say you have a `config.py` which inside has

```
settings = read_yaml('settings.yaml')
```

so `config.settings` is a dictionary.

in one script `foo.py` you have:

```
import config
config.settings['foo'] = str(time.time())
write_yaml('settings.yaml', config.settings)
```

and in another script `bar.py` you have

```
import config
while True:
    sleep(10)
    print config.settings['foo']
```

How would you keep the printed value in `bar.py` up to date with the new value after running `foo.py` at any time without the obvious reading the file again seeing as the while loop in `bar.py` needs to be as quick as possible!

I currently run these on seperate bash threads i.e:

```
$ python bar.py
$ python foo.py
```

But I could run bar in a thread if that is possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files

Comment: Is using any of the standard IPC mechanisms an option for communication between foo and bar?

Comment: I ran `foo.py` from a thread within `bar.py` `threading.Thread()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how fast you need this to be. But it would certainly be possible to just reload the `config` module with [`importlib.reload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload). So `config.py` and `foo.py` stay the same and your `bar.py` changes to:

```
import importlib
import config

while True:
    print config.settings['foo']
    sleep(10)
    importlib.reload(config)
```

---

**Update**

The example above works for Python >= 3.4, use [`imp.reload`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/imp.html#imp.reload) for earlier versions of Python 3 or [`reload`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) for Python 2.