# Sharing variables across modules

Tags: python

I have a program- `main.py` that generates values for a few parameters depending on the user provided inputs. I need to share these variables with other modules- `aux.py`. To do that I did the following (simplified code below) -

This the `main.py` file:

```
# these three variables are dynamically calculated depending on the user provided input
a = 12
b = 13
c = 14

def declare_global():
    global a, b, c

declare_global()
import aux
aux.print_all()
```

This is the `aux.py` file

```
def print_all():
    a = globals()['a']
    b = globals()['b']
    c = globals()['c']
    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(b)
```

Running the `main.py` file results in the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/new/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2018.3/scratches/global_experiment/main.py",
>   line 13, in 
>       aux.print_all()   File "/Users/new/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2018.3/scratches/global_experiment/aux.py",
>   line 2, in print_all
>       a = globals()['a'] KeyError: 'a'

There is a very similar post addressing the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files) but the posts there suggest adding all global variables to a new file and then importing the created file. But I cannot do that as I'll have no prior information as to what values these variables will take.

So, how do I share variables across modules?

**EDIT**

I lost some complexity of the actual program in order to make a minimalistic example. The reason I cannot pass the variables `a,b,c` to the `print_all` function is because in the actual program, the variables `a,b,c` are not serializable. They are spark dataframe objects. And one of the modules I use there (which here I am representing by `print_all`) serializes all its inputs I end up with an error (spark dataframes aren't serializable). Using a few workarounds I have arrived here where I use global variables and no inputs to the functions.

Comment: Why don't you pass the values to the other function? Or have aux its own variables that you modify in `main`? (e.g. `aux.some_variable = a`)

Comment: @h4z3, I have added an edit section. Please check

Comment: why don't you create a python file holds the variables with None as default value?

Comment: I advise you to write a function that serializes the Spark inputs instead.

Comment: @IMCoins,Thanks for the suggestion but the spark inputs are not serializable. They are generally saved as parquet or csv files and secondly, even if they were serializable or I tweaked the function that was serializing them, those spark inputs can be anywhere between a few GBs to a hundred GB or more. The disk space and time required are prohibitively expensive.

Comment: You don't have to print it entirely, that's not my point. The function "print_all" does show something right ? Would it be on stdout or in a file. Well, make a special case to print your Spark Data Frame. You could create a class that would act as a really thin wrapper around Spark DataFrames, and using the __repr__ dunder method, you could have a way to print it. Do you know how __repr__ works ?

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 12
b = 13
c = 14

import aux
aux.print_all(a, b, c)
```

Then your aux file will become:

```
def print_all(a, b, c):
    a = globals()['a']
    b = globals()['b']
    c = globals()['c']
    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(b)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But I cannot use the method you propose. Can you take a look at the edit section once?