# Variable declared but error of not defined shows up in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

**In a nutshell:**

At the end of my program, there is a need to compare two integers whose results are inside the function itself. When I execute, I get undefined variable error.

**Actually:**

I am creating a hand cricket python script which we usually play as a duo. At last both the scores of the opponents are compared and the greatest wins. 
The operation with the variables are inside of a function, but when called outside the function, undefined variable error shows up. Help please?

```
import random  
while True:
    pc_b_or_b = 0  #PC probability

    #User Bowling module
    def Bowl():
        bat_PC = 0
        User_bowl = 0
        scoreofpc = 0
        ScorePC = 0
        while True:
            bat_PC = random.randrange(1,11)                 #Random int gen
            User_bowl = int(input("Your turn to bowl: "))   #int from user
            if User_bowl<1 or User_bowl>10:                 #Fool proofing user must not keep less than 1 or gr8 than 10
                print("Wrong number")
                continue
            if User_bowl == bat_PC:                         # Check if user == pc and out
                print() 
                print("PC Out!")
                print("PC Score:",scoreofpc)
                break
            else:                                           #Continuation
                print("Escape for PC. PC kept",bat_PC)
                scoreofpc += bat_PC
                print("Score:",scoreofpc)
        ScorePC = scoreofpc

    #User batting module
    def User_Batting():
        a = 0
        score = 0
        ManScore = 0
        while True:
            b = random.randrange(1,11)                  #Same as above but User is batting and pc randome int gen
            a = int(input("Your turn to bat: "))        #But here if user int == pc then out for user
            if a<1 or a>10:
                print("Wrong number")
                continue
            if a==b:
                print()
                print("Out")
                print("Score:",score)
                break
            else:
                print("Escape! PC =",b)
                score +=a
                print("Score:",score)
        ManScore = score
```

Actually Some more code comes here I've reduced to just these as said by StackOverflow

Main problem here, variable not defined, all other modules working perfectly

```
    ScorePC1 = ScorePC
    ManScore2 = ManScore

    if ScorePC1 > ManScore2:
        print("PC won the match by scoring",Score_of_PC)
    elif ScorePC1 < ManScore2:
        print("You won the match by scoring",User_Score)
    else:
        print("Your Score and PC score matched!")

    quitter = input("Do you wanna Quit? Y/N? ")
    if quitter == "yes" or quitter == "y" or quitter == "Y":
        print("Thank You for playing!")
        print("Script created by ***Techno-Sachin***")
        quit()
    elif quitter == "n" or quitter == "no" or quitter == "N":
        print("Playing again..")
        continue
    else:
        print("It's a wrong input. Try again")
```

**Expectaion:**

At last it is expected to print the statements inside if ScorePC1 and ManScore2 comparisons.

**Error:**

> The output is Big, but cut out to focus on the problem itself>
>
> PC Out! PC Score: 38 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\E.sachin\Documents\HTML5\Python Scripts\Hand_cricket20.py",
>   line 164, in 
>       ScorePC1 = ScorePC NameError: name 'ScorePC' is not defined

Comment: This is an issue with scope. To fix this you can either make your variables `global` or, have your functions `return` the result. I would recommend the latter. Example `def my_func(): #do some logic return my_var` then `ScorePC=my_func()`

Comment: its a local variable in Bowl, you didn't return it or assign it to a global variable...do what Techno-Sachin said ^^^

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this - `ScorePC1 = ScorePC` with `global ScorePC1` then use it as normal by referencing it's name `ScorePC` anywhere.

using global keyword before a varible name makes the variables's scope global and therefore enables the access to it from outside or inside a function.

also put the same inside the function definition like

```py
def Bowl():
   global ScorePC1
```

use it for both of your variables `ScorePC1` and `ManScore`

Comment: perhaps add an alternative where`Bowl()` `return` `ScorePC1` and vice versa!

Comment: Using a global variable is not advisable in most cases.

Comment: sure but `ScorePC1` variable maintains a state of scoring, it might need updates from various functions so without global it will need referencing from function calls a lot of times. so it is suggested to be used carefully otherwise use function call referencing.

Answer (score 0):

You should always return values from your function. In this case you could return `scoreofpc` and `score` from the two functions. Your code would look like this:

```
def bowl():
    #your code
    return scoreofpc

def user_batting():
    #your code
    return score

Score1 = bowl()
Manscore = user_batting()
```

Alternatively, you could use Global Variables. But they are [not advisable, infact, they're evil](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad).

Answer (score 0):

If the reduced code is inside the main function,then the problem is that `ScorePc`variable is not defined because it is a local variable inside the `Bowl()` function because you initialized it there.You cant access its name in the `main()` function.
To fix this you can either return it from `Bowl()` to the `ScorePc` or set it to be global as Himanshu said.

```
def Bowl():
    #code..
    return ScorePc
def main():
    ScorePc=Bowl()#this will store the returned value to ScorePc
```

or

```
def Bowl():
    global ScorePc
```

You should probably read more about this to understand better how it works.
Here are some links:
[geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/)
[python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: we cannot assign the value in `global` statement

Answer (score 0):

The variable `ScorePC` is declared inside the function `Bowl()` , by doing so the scope of the variable is within the `Bowl()` meaning it cannot be accessed from outside of the function. If you want to access it outside of the function declare it outside, which is not a good design. The better design is to return the value from the function like @irfanuddin answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using `global` keyword in the function. See below for your reference

```py
def Bowl():
    global ScorePc
    ....

def User_Batting():
    global ManScore
    ....
```

But, I would suggest returning the value from the function. if your function is carrying multiple values, then do return as an array.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined **ScorePC** and **ManScore** inside functions which turns out they are only usable inside that function unless you do one of the two things.

1. You can make the variable a function attribute.
   Example:

   ```
   def Bowl():
       Bowl.ScorePC = 0
   def User_Batting():
       User_Batting.ManScore = 0
   ```
2. You can make the variable global.
   Example:

   ```
   def Bowl():
       global ScorePC
       ScorePC = 0
   def User_Batting():
       global ManScore
       ManScore = 0
   ```

If you want to use them in other files. You have to import the file there where you want to use.
Here you will find some good examples:

[Using global variables between files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files)

Answer (score 0):

I did some modifications also.
    import random
    def Bowl():
        global ScorePC
        bat_PC = 0
        User_bowl = 0
        scoreofpc = 0
        ScorePC = 0
        while True:
            bat_PC = random.randrange(1,11)                 #Random int gen
            User_bowl = int(input("Your turn to bowl: "))   #int from user
            if User_bowl<1 or User_bowl>10:                 #Fool proofing user must not keep 
    less than 1 or gr8 than 10
                print("Wrong number")
                continue
            if User_bowl == bat_PC:                         # Check if user == pc and out
                print()
                print("PC Out!")
                print("PC Score:",scoreofpc)
                break
            else:                                           #Continuation
                print("Escape for PC. PC kept",bat_PC)
                scoreofpc += bat_PC
                print("Score:",scoreofpc)
        ScorePC = scoreofpc

```
#User batting module
def User_Batting():
    a = 0
    score = 0
    ManScore = 0
    while True:
        b = random.randrange(1,11)                  #Same as above but User is batting 
and pc randome int gen
        a = int(input("Your turn to bat: "))        #But here if user int == pc then out 
for user
        if a<1 or a>10:
            print("Wrong number")
            continue
        if a==b:
            print()
            print("Out")
            print("Score:",score)
            break
        else:
            print("Escape! PC =",b)
            score +=a
            print("Score:",score)
        ManScore = score

        # Main probem here, variable not defined
        # All other modules wotking perfectly
        ScorePC1 = ScorePC
        ManScore2 = ManScore

    if ScorePC1 > ManScore2:
        print("PC won the match by scoring",ScorePC1)
    elif ScorePC1 < ManScore2:
        print("You won the match by scoring", ManScore2)
    else:
        print("Your Score and PC score matched!")

    quitter = input("Do you wanna Quit? Y/N? ")
    if quitter == "yes" or quitter == "y" or quitter == "Y":
        print("Thank You for playing!")
        print("Script created by ***Techno-Sachin***")
        exit()
    elif quitter == "n" or quitter == "no" or quitter == "N":
        print("Playing again..")
        play()
    else:
        print("It's a wrong input. Try again")

def play():
    Bowl()
    User_Batting()
play()
```

Comment: I have debug your program. And noticed:  I did some modifications also in program.