# Sharing variables across nested folders

Tags: python

## Problem

Many people say their variable-sharing problems are resolved with the approach provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13034908/7784797) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45646477/7784797), but neither of them works in my use case, where all configurations **have to** be written in a class like following.

```py
# config.py
class Config(object):
    var = None
```

The structure of my project looks like

```
├── config.py
├── main.py
├── subfolder
|   ├── change_config.py
```

In this project, `main.py` will invoke `change_config.py` and they both have access to variables defined in `config.py`. Importantly, `change_config.py` will modify the variables (aka., `var`) whose value is only known during runtime.

But it is not clear how I should share the instantiated `Config()` (aka. `opt`) across `main.py` and `change_config.py`. I tried following but no luck. The issue is

- If I instantiated another `Config()` in `change_config.py`, the one in `main.py` will be wiped out.
- If I do not do the first one, then name `opt` would not be resolved in `change_config.py`

```py
# main.py
import config
from subfolder import change_config

opt = config.Config()
print(opt.var)
change_config.change_config()
print(opt.var)
```

```py
# change_config.py
import config

def change_config():
    opt.var = 10
```

## More information

If I run `main.py`, then I will have

```
NameError: name 'opt' is not defined
```

which is expected since `opt` is never declared in `change_config.py`.

If I change `change_config.py` into

```py
# change_config.py
import config

opt = config.Config()
def change_config():
    opt.var = 10
```

where I declared another `opt`. There is no error but returned

```py
None
None
```

which is also expected since `opt` declared in `main.py` is wiped by the one in `change_config.py`. But the expected output should be

```
None 
10
```

So the question is how to share `opt` in `main.py` with `change_config.py`

Comment: Can you share the traceback? I wouldn't expect a `var` does not exist error. Also, `subfolder.change_config` should not be callable since it's a module

Comment: @IainShelvington Thank you for your help! The code turns out to be working fine. But please have a look at the "edit` part for additional issue for my use case.

Comment: Instead of making an edit, could you rewrite your question? The fact that you initially had the import wrong is irrelevant and confusing to the actual issue. Not that finding the solution on your own wasn't commendable.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thank you for your suggestion! Already done that.

Comment: What error do you get? Please post a traceback. Hint, where does `opt` come from in `change_config`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist This is exactly the difficulty I have. I do not know how to pass `opt`  into `change_config` if I could only instantiate it in `main.py`.

Comment: Go ahead and post the traceback for completeness. You're really making this more complicated than it needs to be, and I'll be happy to draft you an answer proving it :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist Please see "more information" part.

Comment: @Mr.Robot why don't you create a single config.py file and declare your variables in there and then just import config.py file in all modules of your application, the module then becomes available as a global name by doing so any changes to the module object get reflected everywhere

Comment: This could be a good case to use the singleton pattern https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Singleton.html you can make Config a singleton which means that there will only be one instance of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start by looking at what the differences between `Config.var` and `Config().var` are in python terms. Like everything else in Python, a class is an object. A class has a namespace, so `Config.var` is a variable in that namespace.

When you instantiate `Config`, say with `opt = Config()`, opt is now an object, also with a namespace. At first, when you request the value `opt.var`, it returns `Config.var` because of how inheritance works in general: if an object does not have an attribute, you look in the class, and then in the parent class, etc. But when you assign `opt.var = 10`, you are assigning into the namespace of the instance. Now, when you request the value of `opt.var`, it does not look at `Config.var` any more, because `opt` has its own `var` attribute.

Now keep in mind that `opt` in `main` and `opt` in `change_config` are completely different instances that do not affect each other except that they share the same class. So when you set `change_config.opt.var = 10`, requesting `main.opt.var` still returns `None`, because the actual attribute `main.opt.var` does not exist as such: it is returning `Config.var` from the class namespace.

So now you have a couple of options available to you.

1. The first is not to bother instantiating anything at all. You can keep your class variable `config.Config.var`, and just update in the class namespace. The code would look like this:

   **main.py**

   ```
   from config import Config
   from subfolder.change_config import change_config

   print(Config.var)
   change_config()
   print(Config.var)
   ```

   **config.py**

   ```
   class Config:
       var = None
   ```

   **subfolder/change_config.py**

   ```
   from config import Config

   def change_config():
       Config.var = 10
   ```

   Aside from changing your imports to relative imports and removing the explicit inheritance from `object`, your code is only modified to use `Config` as a namespace, without instantiating it.
2. A second approach would be to instantiate `Config`, but put the reference in a place that can be accessed by everyone that needs it. At that point, `config.py` should really be maintaining the shared reference, since that is what stores the actual configuration. I would also recommend removing the class variable `Config.var` entirely, to avoid exactly the type of confusion you are having now:

   **main.py**

   ```
   from config import opt
   from subfolder.change_config import change_config

   print(opt.var)
   change_config()
   print(opt.var)
   ```

   **config.py**

   ```
   class Config:
       def __init__(self):
           self.var = None

   opt = Config()
   ```

   **subfolder/change_config.py**

   ```
   from config import opt

   def change_config():
       opt.var = 10
   ```

   You could commit to making your configuration an instance of `Config` even deeper by adding `del Config` to the end of `config.py`. This will make it much more difficult to create another, conflicting instance of the class, since it will not be readily available through the module. The only reference to `Config` will be through the inheritance hierarchy of `opt` at that point.

Answer (score -1):

you can change your application like below, this will help you

in `config.py`

```
x = 0
```

in `change_config.py`

```
import config

def change_config():
    config.x = 10 #change the global config variable
```

and in `main.py`

```
import config
from subfolder import change_config

print(config.x)
change_config.change_config()
print(config.x)
```

you will get output like below after you run `main.py`

```
0
10
```

**EDIT**

using ***singleton*** class

in `config.py`

```
class Config(object):
    var = None
    def __new__(cls):
        if not hasattr(cls, 'instance'):
            cls.instance = super(Config, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls.instance
```

in `main.py`

```
from config import Config
from subfolder import change_config

opt = Config()
print('memory address :%s'%id(opt))
print(opt.var)
change_config.change_config()
print(opt.var)
```

in `change_config.py`

```
from config import Config

opt = Config()
print('memory address :%s'%id(opt))
def change_config():
    opt.var = 10
```

You will get output like below

```
memory address :140185708587536
memory address :140185708587536
None
10
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tried this one and this indeed worked. But according to my use case, all configurations **have to** be written in the class `Config()` and this is the difficulty I am facing.

Comment: Singleton class seems possible solution for your problem. Create singleton Config class and import it wherever you require, in this way you can access/change the configurations without creating multiple objects of Config class