# Synchronizing global variables between files

Tags: python

I want to modify a global variable in different python files, and I read about this thread: [Using global variables between files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files)

In the above example, the global variable is a list reference so the modification of the list elements can be correctly done. However, if the global variable is, for example, a string, then it doesn't work.

In the below code, I try to modify the global variable defined in `setting.py`.

```
## setting.py
s = 'setting'

## main.py
from setting import s
import dau1
import dau2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(s)
    print('After mother')
    s = 'mother'
    print(s)
    dau1.dau1call()
    print(s)
    dau2.dau2call()
    print(s)

## dau1.py
from setting import s
def dau1call():
    global s
    print('After dau1')
    s = 'dau1'

## dau2.py
from setting import s
def dau2call():
    global s
    print('After dau2')
    s = 'dau2'
```

The result is

```
setting
After mother
mother
After dau1
mother
After dau2
mother
```

Is there any way to modify a global variable in different .py files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the question you reference, the answers had you `import setting` not `from settings import s`. In the second case, you rebind the object referenced by `settting.s` to a module-scoped variable `__main__.s` in your `main` module. Both of these variables, `setting.s` and `__main__.s` reference the same object until you assign something new to `__main__.s`. Then these two variables are different.

There are no truly global variables. Except for some variables builtin to python, all variables are local to a module, a class or a function.

### setting.py

```
s = 'setting'
```

### main.py

```
import setting
import dau1
import dau2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(setting.s)
    print('After mother')
    setting.s = 'mother'
    print(setting.s)
    dau1.dau1call()
    print(setting.s)
    dau2.dau2call()
    print(setting.s)
```

### dau1.py

```
import setting
def dau1call():
    print('After dau1')
    setting.s = 'dau1'
```

### dau2.py

```
import setting
def dau2call():
    print('After dau2')
    setting.s = 'dau2'
```

Answer (score 0):

For `dau1.py`:

```
import setting
def dau1call():
    print('After dau1')
    setting.s = 'dau1'
```

The original `from setting import s` creates a new variable `s` in module `dau1` which holds its own reference to the string.