# Accessing python variables from other python modules, which are inside a function

Tags: python, function, variables, module

I'm pretty new to python, and I am have a problem in one of my projects that I can't get over with, no matter how many articles I read.

So I have two .py files.

The First One: (first.py)

```
from second import *
function(10, 30)
print(answer)
```

The Second One: (second.py)

```
def function(one, two):
     global answer
     answer = one + two
```

So second.py creates a global variable, and first.py imports second.py, and tries to print out my_var. But for some reason I always get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "first.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(answer)
AttributeError: module 'second' has no attribute 'answer'
```

...

May I ask for some help, please? I was really trying, but for the sake of Lord I could not figure it out!

Comment: you can use `return` in `function`

Comment: It would be better if you made the function return the answer instred of making a global var.

Comment: You may find your answer in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you made your function return a the value:

```py
def function(one, two):
     answer = one + two
     return answer
```

then you could setup your other file like this:

```
from second import function
answer = function(10, 30)
print(answer)
```

also function is a terrible name for a function call it something descriptive

Comment: Thank you this seems to be working, but now I have another issue. What should I do if I need to return multiple answers? 

PS: I've changed the name of the function

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this question is answered in another way, you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files). You have defined `global answer` inside a function (not outside the function and without assigning any value for it), so at `import` time, this variable, even with its global nature, is not declared yet. without too much details about how to refactor your solution, you just need `first.py` to be written that way:

```
import second
second.function(10, 30)
print(second.answer)
```

This way, you have not changed `second.py`, and also imported the global variable as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

well, let me explain what happens when you import something from one script to another. when, you write:

```
from second import *
```

it copies the names from `second.py` into the namespace of `first.py`. So, if you reassign any variable of `second.py`(in you case `answer`) in `first.py`, the change will only be done in `first.py`, not in `second.py`. So, I hope you've understood that, `first.py's` `answer` and `second.py's` `answer` each of them have occupied different memory location. For your understanding I've written a test, read the code and see the output, you'll understand what's happen when you import something:

**second.py**

```
answer = 0 # you've to declare "answer" as as global variable
           # this is one mistake you've done in your code

def function(one, two):
    global answer
    answer = one + two

def print_answer_in_second():
    print("in second: {}".format(answer))
```

**first.py**:

```
from second import *

print("in first: {}".format(answer))
print_answer_in_second()

function(10, 30) # calling function() to change answer value in second.py

print("in first: {}".format(answer))
print_answer_in_second()

answer = 100 + 800; # changing answer value in first.py

print("in first: {}".format(answer))
print_answer_in_second()
```

**output**:

```
in first: 0
in second: 0
in first: 0
in second: 40
in first: 900
in second: 40
```

I hope, you get the idea around import.

Now, how can we solve this problem beautifully? Global variables are essential part of a language, the programming world can't run without the existence of `globals`. But `globals` also create problems. It's hard to maintain `globals`. So, what would be the best practice with `globals`?

Well, if you're developing an app or any project, the best practice to put the `globals` of your app or project in a single file, so that, we may easily find them and change their values. Let's call our `global file` `glob.py`. Here's the code for `glob.py`:

**glob.py:**

```
# declaring global answer
answer = 0
```

Now, let's declare `new_second.py`:

**new_second.py**:

```
import glob

def function(a, b):
    glob.answer = a + b

def print_answer_in_second():
    print("In second: {}".format(glob.answer))
```

**new_first.py**:

```
import glob

from new_second import function, print_answer_in_second
# note: "import ... from *" is a very bad practice
#       so, avoid use that style of import

function(10, 30)

print("In first: {}".format(glob.answer))
print_answer_in_second()
```

**output**:

```
In first: 40
In second: 40
```

I hope, you get the idea of how to use `globals` properly without affecting too much other parts of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `return`. If you want to return multiple answers, try the following.

first.py:

```py
from second import function

ans1, ans2 = function(1, 2, 3)
print(ans1, ans2) # 3 5
```

second.py:

```py
def function(one, two, three):
    answer1 = one + two
    answer2 = two + three
    return answer1, answer2
```