# Python: Using a dictionary across modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code has the following structure:

```
main.py
utilities.py
generator.py
motor.py
```

The `main` module calls the other modules as per logic and all this works properly. I'm at a point where I need to keep a running track of data being generated by the called modules. One option would be to initialize an object (could be as simple as a basic dictionary) within `main` and pass it as an argument to each call to the called modules who update the object as necessary and then return the object back.

I'm wondering if there's a better way to accomplish this. Based on some preliminary code investigation, there are hundreds of calls being done all over the place and it would be very tedious/manual/error-prone to edit all these calls.

Ideally I'd be looking at a way to update the tracker object globally without having to explicitly pass it in as an argument to the method calls.

Is this possible, or is there a better way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using global variables between files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files)

Answer (score 0):

Honestly you could output the tracker to an out file and use that file as a median. Not much of a better way though.

Comment: *Not much of a better way though.* - yes, there are a few...