# How to call a DataFrame that is build in another module/method?

Tags: python

probably a simple question but I can't find any solution.

I do have a file called irc_daten.py, where I built a class, called IrcData, that contains various methods. This methods collect several data in DataFrames that will be used in many files by importing the methods. But somehow I can't call this DataFrames.

This is irc_daten.py:

```
class IrcDaten():
    
    def __init__(self):
        pass
        
    def stammdaten():
        global stammdaten
        stammdaten = pd.read_excel(path_stammdaten)
```

But using this DataFrame in another file doesn't seem to work:

```
from irc_daten import IrcDaten
IrcDaten.stammdaten()

print(stammdaten)

NameError: name 'stammdaten' is not defined
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using global variables between files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this instead:

```
class IrcDaten():
    
    def __init__(self):
        pass
        
    def stammdaten():
        stammdaten = pd.read_excel(path_stammdaten)
        return stammdaten

from irc_daten import IrcDaten
df = IrcDaten.stammdaten()
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Sometimes it's that easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try importing in this way:

```
from irc_daten import IrcDaten as ID
y=ID.stammdaten()

print(y)
```