# Refresh config variable value on every call to it

Tags: python

A module is having variables like below

config.py

```
var_a = <some value that can change>
```

If the above variable is called in some another module then it will give you same value if running in some kind of server. I am using flask server.

module_b.py

```
from config import var_a
print(var_a)
```

I want the value of var_a will change after every call to it

Comment: Why don't you just simply call `uuid.uuid4()` when you need a new value? That is much more explicit.

Comment: Variables are not called, they are accessed. If you want a different value, then call a function. You already have one of those. Use: `print(uuid.uuid4())`

Comment: For example, I have used uuid to convey the message that the value is dynamically changing. For example, if I am getting config values from third party and that may change that's why needed this solution

Comment: Hope now its okay and easy to understand

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using global variables between files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files)

Comment: Have you tried importing it like: `import config` and then using it like: `print(config.var_a)`? I think it should work.

Comment: It will give you static value will not change on every call

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the `var_a` with different value each time, you can wrap it with `property`:

**config.py:**

```
import uuid

class MyConfig:
    @property
    def var_a(self):
        return uuid.uuid4()

my_conf = MyConfig()
```

**module_b.py:**

```
from config import my_conf

print(my_conf.var_a)
print(my_conf.var_a)
```

Comment: I applied this type of solution already but it's quite a mess when you are having too many variables in the config and you will create a property for all those variables

Comment: @AnandTripathi You don't need `property` at all. You can just access the attributes and override `__getattribute__`

Comment: Can you give an example of it!!

Comment: @Tomerikoo can you give an example of it

Answer (score 1):

you can use class methods:

**config.py**

```
class var:
    def __init__(self, executable):
        self.executable = executable
     
    def __repr__(self):
        # here change/refresh val, maybe recalling it
        return str(self.executable())

    def __eq__(self, other):
        #here you compare the new value with another one, it's called when you do val_a == other
        if self.executable() == other:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

**module_b.py**

```
import uuid
from config import var
var_a = var(uuid.uuid4)
print(var_a)
```

In this way every time you print your `var_a` it will change.

But surely the easiest way would be not to store `uuid.uuid4()` and simply calling it:

```
print(uuid.uuid4())
```

But if you can't do it I think that the class alternative is the best one.

note that using `__repr__` will work only if you want the value to be retured as string, else you have to create a new method and call it instead of print

**config.py**

```
class var:
    def __init__(self, executable):
        self.executable = executable
     
    def __eq__(self, other):
        #here you compare the new value with another one, it's called when you do val_a == other
        if self.executable() == other:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def get(self):
        # here change/refresh val, maybe recalling it
        return self.executable()
```

**module_b.py**

```
import uuid
from config import var
var_a = var(uuid.uuid4)
print(var.get())
```

Comment: I would say that this is a problematic design. You generally don't want the representation function to change the values. And it's also confusing that the `value` of the object is actually a callable returning a value, and not really a *value*

Comment: is it better now?

Comment: In my opinion, a lot! Only issue is that `callable` is a built-in function so I would change that name

Comment: note that i prefer the second version with `var_a.get()` too, but i made also the one with `__repr__()` because in the question he used `print(var_a)`

Comment: @LeonardoScotti just another requirement do you know how can I override the type of var class to str!!

Comment: do you want var class to be a str?

Comment: let say the output is 111-111 and you do var_a == '111-111' then it evaluates to false cause, __repr__ doesnt return the type of the value it is always the type of class.

Comment: I want if I am retrning the value from __repr__ as str then it should be comapared to str and actually work like str if __repr__ is returning list then it should be list

Comment: you could overwrite another builtin class method, the `__eq__` one, i edited the answer, take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

If you import the module like so: `import config` and then use it like so: `print(config.var_a)` it should work.
**Demonstration:**
config.py

```py
var_a = 0
```

second.py

```py
import config
def change_var_a():
    config.var_a = 1
```

main.py

```py
import config
import second

assert config.var_a == 0
second.change_var_a()
assert config.var_a == 1
```