# Sync change of variables between files python

Tags: python, python-packaging

I would like to share a variable between files.

B.py

```
b_var = 'start'

def change_var():
    global b_var
    b_var = 'changed'
```

test.py

```
from proj.B import change_var, b_var

print(b_var)
change_var()
print(b_var)
```

The output is:

```
start
start
```

How can I get the output to be:

```
start
changed
```

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files) answer your question.

Comment: @Ceres Actually no because a list is mutable so it can work this way but a string isn't...

Comment: @lordcommander, use `from proj import B`

Comment: @OlvinRoght Nice. But is there a way that i could write b_var instead of B.b_var and it will still work?

Comment: @lordcommander, there's but not as short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that as soon as you use a simple variable, you have lost. Because when you use (whatever value can be):

```
var = value
```

you do not try to change the object that `var` previouly refered to, but just make `var` point to a different object. So any other variables that pointed to the original object are not affected.

So you will have to use an attribute on a mutable object (here the module), or an element of a container. That way, the object itself will the changed and all variables pointing to that object will reflect the change. Of course if at any point of your program you have a simple variable pointing to the attribute, this one will not reflect the change.

So this would be ok:

```
from proj.B import change_var   # change_var will not change: we directly import it
import B

print(B.b_var)      # but we use b_var (expected to change) through another object
change_var()
print(B.b_var)
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution similar to the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules)

B.py

```py
b_var = 'start'
```

mod.py

```py
import B

def change_var():
    B.b_var = 'changed'
```

test.py

```py
import B
import mod
print(B.b_var)
mod.change_var()
print(B.b_var)
```

output

```
start
changed
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `b_var` is not a variable, is a reference to an immutable string.

The import sentence is copying the reference, and when `change_var()` runs it creates a new string and change only the reference on `B` module but not on `test` one.