# mutable datatype similar to string in python

Tags: python-3.x, string, import, python-module, mutable

I have 2 files let say them `a.py` and `b.py`, `b.py` has a global variable let say `test`(data type is a string), and I’m importing `test` in `a.py`. Now, during runtime, a function in `a.py` calls a function of `b.py`, and that function changed the value of `test` in `b.py` but this change doesn’t show in `a.py` because the test is of string datatype and string is immutable.

I tried using the list, and it works, but I’m not feeling very good about using a list with one element in it. So, is there any mutable data type(similar to string) that I can use for this purpose?.

Code when the `test` is string.

b.py

```py
test = "hello"
def changeTest():
    global test
    test = "hii"
```

a.py

```py
from b import test,changeTest

def callFunctionInB():
    changeTest()
    
print(test)
callFunctionInB()
print(test)
```

output:

```
hello
hello
```

Code when the test is list.

b.py

```py
test = ["hello"]
def changeTest():
    test[0] = "hii"
```

a.py

```py
from b import test,changeTest

def callFunctionInB():
    changeTest()
    
print(test)
callFunctionInB()
print(test)
```

output:

```
['hello']
['hii']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python import statements are extremely tricky, and your issue is because of poor usage of import statements.

`from ... import ...` creates a copy of imported variable for reference. To validate this on your copy of python, try running:

```
### a.py
import b
from b import string_value, change_value

print(string_value)
change_value("new value")
print(string_value)
print("a.py ==> b.string_value = \t", id(b.string_value))
print("a.py ==> string_value = \t", id(string_value))
```

```
### b.py
string_value = "previous"

def change_value(given_value):
    global string_value
    print("b.py ==> 'global' string_value \t", id(string_value))
    string_value = given_value
```

Import statement in `a.py` is creating a copy of the variable for itself, so when you update the global variable of module b, it has no effect on the variable in a.

To answer your question, there are a couple of possibilities:

1. Use module level import. Don't use `from ... import ...`.
   Example of this would be:

```
### a.py
import b

print(b.string_value)
b.change_value("new value")
print(b.string_value)
```

```
### b.py
string_value = "previous"

def change_value(given_value):
    global string_value
    string_value = given_value
```

2. Use a third `c.py` configuration file or even better create a class for your use case with complete getters and setters. This is the best approach. Follow this approach for clean and maintainable code base. Lots of other SO answers have good documentation around this. Like [Using global variables between files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files)
3. If you absolutely have to use `from ... import ...`, you can use an ugly update syntax. **Please avoid this at all costs**. One of the above two things should be easily feasible. For your reference, sample code to do this would be:

```
### a.py
from b import string_value, change_value

print(string_value)
change_value("new value")
print(string_value)
```

```
### b.py
# Please don't use this code except for understanding purpose
import sys
string_value = "previous"

def change_value(given_value):
    sys.modules['__main__'].string_value = given_value
```

Comment: Woah, Thanks, it worked. I understood the mistake I was making. I currently shifted to suggestion 1.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem lies solely with the implementation of b.py. In that given:

```
test = ["hello"]
def changeTest():
    test[0] = "hii"
```

the variable test within the changeTest function is defined locally, not globally.  By using:
test = "hello"

```
def changeTest():
    global test
    test = "hii"
```

You will directly update the global variable test.

Comment: I got your point. But even after making the test global in the changeTest it's not working. I also updated the code for clarity.