# How to persist variables across multiple module instances?

Tags: python-3.x

When developing an application, I found out that it is hard to persist variables across imports. Perhaps it would be easier to explain with an example:

```py
# a.py
v = []

def add_to_v():
    global v
    v.append(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(v)

# b.py

from a import add_to_v

add_to_v()
add_to_v()
```

Expected output: `[1, 1]`. Actual output: `[]`.

I think that I can solve this problem by persisting the variable to a file, but there must be a more elegant solution. Why does this happen and how can I solve this problem elegantly without writing the variable to a file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using global variables between files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files)

Comment: Yes, it does! Thanks!