# python - sharing global variables across files. how it works?

Tags: python, global-variables

I am searching for a method to sharing a global variable across multiple files. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files) and the second answer brought me [here](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules). So now I know how to do it. For example:

```py
# config.py
THIS_IS_A_GLOBAL_VARIABLE = 1
```

```py
# sub.py
import config

def print_var():
    print('global variable: ', config.THIS_IS_A_GLOBAL_VARIABLE)
```

```py
# main.py
import config
from sub import print_var

print_var()   # global variable:  1

config.THIS_IS_A_GLOBAL_VARIABLE = 2
print_var()   # global variable:  2
```

This is exactly what I want.

The question is, I am curious that why it works? [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules) is a simple explanation: `Because there is only one instance of each module, any changes made to the module object get reflected everywhere`. But I still don't fully understand it. Is there any further explanation about it?
Very thanks!

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: It works because there is only one `config` module when your program runs.  A module is an object, just like other objects.  So, both `sub.py` and `main.py` are importing the same module object.  When you change a member in that object, everyone with a reference to that object will see it.  main.py imports it first.  When sub.py imports it, it's already in the global module list, so it just takes a second reference to that module object.

Comment: @quamrana yes I know it, I use the global variable for the convenience. Without the global variable it would be much complex. And I only use one global variable. Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for your explanation! But I have another question. Why it still works if I change the import order? That is, if I import `sub` first and then import `config`, it still works.

Comment: There's still only one `config` module object.  The order doesn't matter.  The first one in causes the file to be read and interpreted.  The second one just get a reference to the existing object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bit that works is here: `config.THIS_IS_A_GLOBAL_VARIABLE = 2`

What is happening is that `config` is a reference to the module `config.py`. Then `THIS_IS_A_GLOBAL_VARIABLE` is one of the attributes in that module and the above assignment make the attribute refer to a different object.

Now, *any* other module which has the line: `import config` refers to the same module and when you fetch any attributes you get hold of the same references.

Comment: If I modify `main.py`: `from config import THIS_IS_A_GLOBAL_VARIABLE`, it would make a copy of `THIS_IS_A_GLOBAL_VARIABLE` in `main.py`. And if I change the value of `THIS_IS_A_GLOBAL_VARIABLE` in `main.py`, the result of `print_var` would not be affected because I just modify a local variable in `main.py`. Did I understand it correctly?