# Working with variables that are global in scope in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, scope, global-variables

I'm working on creating a python program and I just finished the login/signup functionality. It would be ideal for me to have a `user` variable (that contains user info) that I could reference throughout the application. How would I do that? Is the answer just constantly passing around a variable from file to file (that seems a little tedious) or is there another solution.

In the same vein, I also want to do some state management (was looking at maybe using a library like pytransitions) that would keep track of different user states. Is there a way to have the state be globally accessible throughout the application? That would make it really easily to access and change the state as needed.

I know there are global variables in python but it seems like those are just 'global' within a file. So if I have `file1.py` with a global variable called `someVar`, that won't, per my understanding, be accessible within another file `file2.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move all globals to a file, I call this file settings.py. This file is responsible for defining globals and initializing them:

```
# settings.py

def init():
    global myList
    myList = []
```

Next, your subfile can import globals:

```
# subfile.py

import settings
```

credits to [globalvariables between files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files)