# How to share a global class instance in python across files?

Tags: python, module, dependencies, global-variables

Recently I started with python3 to write an interpreter for some simple language. All went fine until I tried to separate the modules into separate files. What you can read everywhere is to create a global file where you create the global variable, import it from the other files and use them with the file's prefix, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13034908/7690354).

But what if the variable I want to share is the instance of a class defined in one of the files?

`globals.py`:

```
def init(param):
    global myGlobal
    myGlobal = MyClass(param)
```

`classes.py`:

```
import globals

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param = param
    def foo(self):
        param += 1
    def other(self, o):
        o.doSomething()

class OtherClass:
    def bar(self):
        global.myGlobal.foo()
    def doSomething(self):
        pass
```

`main.py`:

```
import globals
from classes import MyClass, OtherClass

globals.init(42)
x = OtherClass()
x.bar()
globals.myGlobal.foo()
```

It seems I need to initialize `myGlobal` in `globals.py`, but `globals.py` must not know about the classes from `classes.py`. How to proceed?

Comment: Why don't you pass `ep` as argument to your `error` function?

Comment: @Tranbi Would that work even if `error` doesn't know what an `ExecutionPointer` is? And still `ep` is instanced in `xMain`, but needs to be known in `xClasses`, but it would mess up code to always give it as parameter for each and every call ...

Comment: `error` can take an `ExecutionPointer` as argument without importing the class in `xTools`. However, you might want to rethink your design. Have you considered implementing `error` as a class method?

Comment: Yes, this question is about I want to rethink my design. I just can't see how. Making `error` a method of `Execution Pointer` did indeed solve this piece, but I have lots of other places where I need to access `ep` in both files.

Comment: @Tranbi I tried to make the question clearer now.